# I want to fetch the date_part and runid from the path of s3 for snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a S3 path "S3:sample/logs/datepart=20220210/runid=2/". It consist of my data files inside this path.I want to create the datepart and runid as a partition using  the external stage of the snowflake. Can you please help me in providing the query for it. How can i fetch the date part and runid.

Answer (score 0):

I understood you load the files and also want to process these two parameters - runid and datepart.

You can include the METADATA$FILENAME in your loading-process with the COPY INTO and then process further with SQL (SUBSTR, LEFT/RIGHT, ...)

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-metadata.html